# Automating rendering with aerender to mp4

Tags: command-line, adobe, render, mp4, after-effects

How can I automatically render a Composition to an .mp4 with aerender?

This renders the Composition to an .avi:

```
aerender -project C:\aeProjects\anim.aep -comp "Main Pogo" -output C:\aeProjects\output\test.avi
```

I tried to replace .avi with .mp4 like this:

```
aerender -project C:\aeProjects\anim.aep -comp "Main Pogo" -output C:\aeProjects\output\test.mp4
```

but did not work.

Does anyone know a solution or a workaround how to accomplish this in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just saw this tonight. The way to do this is make an output template, one that has the mp4 settings in it, then include it by name by using the -OMtemplate parameter flag, like:

```
aerender -project C:\aeProjects\anim.aep -comp "Main Pogo" -OMtemplate "nameOfmp4Template" -output C:\aeProjects\output\test.mp4
```